# update table syntax: query works in mysql , but does not in oracle or mssql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

```
update t_one t1 
join t_two t2 on (t2.f1 = t1.f1)
join t_three t3 on (t1.f4 = t3.f4 and t2.f5 = t3.f5) 
set t1.f6 = t3.f6 
where t1.f6 is null
```

I want to update t_on.f6 with a corresponding value in t_three that depends on a join. The query works very well in mysql, but I get

An error in ORACLE

> ORA-00971: missing SET keyword

and in MSSQL

> Error in query: Incorrect syntax near 't1'

What can I do about that?

Comment: Different flavours of SQL are akin to different programming languages: they may be similar but are never going to be the same. You're essentially asking us to convert some code from one language to another.

Comment: For Oracle: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/8061/update-with-joins#t=201702011807246703976

Comment: UPDATE aliasName SET table.column = value FROM tableONE aliasName INNER JOIN tableTwo ON aliasName.ColumnX = tableTwo.ColumnY, etc, etc.

Comment: @pmbAustin - for which DBMS? That wouldn't fly in Oracle.

Comment: SQL Server... any version.

Comment: @cybermonkey. Exactly. I wish there were an online tool doing the same thing.

Comment: @Ferenjito Then your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Isn't that what Stackoverflow is about? Programers helping each other? What do I misunderstand?

Answer (score 2):

I can never remember which order the various clauses appear in, but it's something along the lines of

```
update t1 
set t1.f6 = t3.f6 
from t_one t1
join t_two t2 on (t2.f1 = t1.f1)
join t_three t3 on (t1.f4 = t3.f4 and t2.f5 = t3.f5) 
where t1.f6 is null
```

You may not need the `t1` aliases in the `set` or `where` clauses, but they probably won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

You want something more like this for SQL Server:

```
UPDATE t1 
   SET t1.f6 = t3.f6 
  FROM t_one t1 
       INNER JOIN t_two t2 ON t2.f1 = t1.f1
       INNER JOIN t_three t3 ON t1.f4 = t3.f4 AND t2.f5 = t3.f5 
 WHERE t1.f6 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server:

```
update  t1 
set t1.f6 = t3.f6 
from t_one t1
join t_two t2 on (t2.f1 = t1.f1)
join t_three t3 on (t1.f4 = t3.f4 and t2.f5 = t3.f5) 
where t1.f6 is null
```